# How to delete and erase in a map with a pair and pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have a map declared in this way:

```
static map<string, pair<Socket*,queue<string>*>> panels;
```

where Socket is a user defined class to encapsulate Linux sockets. Socket* is used as a pointer to an automatic allocated variable, the queue is dynamically allocated.
I insert new elements in map in this way:

```
panels.insert(make_pair(cdhw, make_pair(&sock, new queue<string>())));
```

When I have to erase an element of the map I do this:

```
delete( (panels.find(cdhw))->second.second ); //delete queue
panels.erase(cdhw);
```

cdhw is a string to identify the panel.

Is this a correct way to delete and erase? Are there issues using pointers in a map and/or a pair? After the erase I get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" but I don't understand if the problem is in deletion or other code (possibly related to multithreading).

Comment: You're not doing any of this when `sock` is already out of scope, are you?

Comment: For starters, don't dynamically allocate the queue. That will cause only pain.

Comment: You'd better use a smart pointer for your queue

Comment: Storing pointers in containers like that can be a bit risky, especially if your Socket* is an automatic variable.

Comment: @Antonio: No, just store the queue directly. An extra layer of indirection serves no purpose here.

Comment: Your debugger can tell you exactly what causes the segmentation fault. It's hard to guess from the code fragments what exactly might be going wrong; but some combination of manual pointer-juggling and multithreading is almost certainly going to cause you to delete an object or invalidate a pointer before you've finished with it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I simply answer to the question in the title. You're probably right that in this use case an extra layer of indirections is not needed, but it would be if the queue was a more complex object to be created before storing it in the map, so knowing about shared pointers is good exercise.

Comment: *"Is this a correct way to delete and erase?"* - Well, it isn't the correct way to put a queue into a map in the first place.

Comment: @Antonio While knowing about smart pointers is a good exercise, it does far more bad than good when learned incorrectly as a way to accommodate for lacking knowledge about proper value semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when you call `find`, that you definitely have the element in the map? You could add this, to check the element was found:

```
auto It = panels.find(cdhw);
if(It != panels.end())
{
    // The element was found
    delete((It->second.second); //delete queue
    panels.erase(cdhw);
}
else
{
    // The element was not found, is this an error case?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `static` variable for your map together with `Socket*` allocated on stack (automatic variable) sounds like horrible idea. If you simply move to to dynamically allocated Sockets it should improve things.

Comment: Why?  If automatic scope works for `Socket`, it is certainly preferable.

Comment: Using `static` assumes that he returns from function and reuses that variable upon next call, or uses variable outside of scope of any function. In both cases, storing pointers to automatic variables is a recipe for disaster

Comment: It depends on the lifetime of `Socket`.  Obviously, leaving a pointer in the map after the lifetime has ended isn't a good idea, but this is independent of whether `Socket` is allocated on the stack or not.  (In the usual design of such things, the constructor of `Socket` will do the insertion, and its destructor will remove it from the map.  And it's quite frequent for something like `Socket` to be on the stack.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: in this particular case, OP stated: "Socket* is used as a pointer to an automatic allocated variable". In other words, he allocates Socket structure on stack. This is huge red flag as far as I am concerned.

Comment: It is, never the less, the usual pattern in servers; the `Socket` has a lifespan of a connection, each connection is in a separate thread, and is the lowest level function in that thread.  The `Socket` object is naturally a local variable, and will be inserted and removed from any maps, etc. which hold it using RAII techniques.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, in c++11 you are much better off using things by value because with move semantics you don't pay any overhead for copy constructors.  So you would define your map like this:

```
map<string, pair<Socket *, queue<string>>> panels ;
```

And you could further optimize your create with:

```
panels.emplace(cdhw, make_pair(&sock, queue<string>()));
```

Then erase is simply:

```
panels.erase( cdhw ) ;
```